# Physical file name for filetable sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, ifilter, filetable

I'm creating a custom IFilter for sqlserver, for a my extension (we can call it "abc"). The abc files are generic crypted files, that have originally a different extension and that are recorded in a sqlserver filetable. When I copy a file into my filetable, I crypt the file, I changhe the extension in abc and I record the original extension in another table of same db.
When my IFilter starts, it receives a file with abc extension but his name is created by sqlserver and it doesn't have any connection with the name of the file stored in filetable. 
If I could retrieve, from that name, the record in filetable, then my problem would be solved.

Thanks in advance
Luigi

Answer (score 0):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
SELECT 
      f.directory_name
    , f.filename_collation_id
    , f.filename_collation_name 
FROM sys.filetables f
JOIN sys.tables t ON f.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
WHERE f.is_enabled = 1
    AND t.name = 'table1'
```

This query returns list of all active filetables on server.

Comment: Thank you, but I need for the name of a single file in the filetable not just of the filetable itself.